# How to take the previous entries for an id

Tags: java, database, postgresql

I am having a database table in postgresql like below

```
entry_no      id            time
________     ____          ______

 1            1             2017-03-21 00:12:10
 2            2             2017-03-21 00:12:18 
 3            3             2017-03-21 00:12:56
 4            2             2017-03-21 10:25:34
 5            1             2017-03-21 11:09:10
 6            2             2017-03-21 11:21:39
 7            3             2017-03-21 12:19:19
 8            3             2017-03-21 12:29:19
 9            1             2017-03-21 12:39:10
 10           1             2017-03-21 12:39:10
```

I am having a Java Program which has to detect the previous entry for an id. For example if the entry is of id 2

```
 6            2             2017-03-21 11:21:39
```

From this entry I need to take the previous entry of the respective id which is

```
 4            2             2017-03-21 10:25:34
```

the entry no is a primary key.So if I can find the entry_no it will be fast enough to find the previous entry of the respective id.

Since the table is big I don't want to sort the whole table and filter by id and then get the previous id.Is there any effective way?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the logic by which you selected the first record with id `2`?  Is that the most _recent_ record, or did you use some other logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using Postgres' `LAG()` analytic function, and use it on the `time` column.  The CTE below assigns the lag of the `time` to each record.  Then, we can select the record whose previous value you want, and it should already be there in the result set.  Note that the CTE uses `WHERE id = 2` to ensure that we assign the lag time appropriately only for that block of records.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT entry_no, id, time,
           LAG(time) OVER (ORDER BY time) lag_time
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE id = 2
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE entry_no = 6
```

Follow the link below for a running demo:

## Rextester

Comment: I tried your sql but it is not responding with the lag_time.I could not figure ouy why it does not return the lag_time

Comment: @Ricky I setup a Postgres demo for you.  I would recommend studying it to see where you might be going wrong.

Comment: I am so sorry that I made a mistake in the id and the entry no. Thanks for the fiddle. But still as I said the table is big it takes a lot of time to each record.Anyway to make it more faster

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to add another column `previous_entry_no` which will obviously contain the previous entry number and which you can extract.

The downsides of this approach: you need an additional column and before each insertion you need to execute an additional query to find the latest `entry_no` for the given `id`.

Comment: Actually the database table is so big(In Billions).So it is actually not easy to add another column

Comment: @Ricky, I see. Then you can probably try to use compare the records in the time column.